# How to add copy right notice on first page

Tags: titles

I want to add a copyright notice on the first page of the manuscript, like this [one.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06504.pdf)

I used this code

```
\newpage \null \thispagestyle{headings} 
Notice:This work has been submitted to the IEEE for possible publication. 
Copyright may be transferred without notice, after which this version may no 
longer be accessible.\newpage
```

But problem is that

- this notice does not appear as title, instead it appears as normal text in two-column page.
- It also adds page number to this notice page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have helped greatly if you had provided an MWE but as it is we have to guess.

The following works for me but I don't really know what you have done.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\onecolumn % switch to one column
\pagestyle{empty} % don't print page number
\begin{center}
  \large\bfseries  % font for your notice
  Your copyright notice
\end{center}
\twocolumn % switch to 2 columns
\setcounter{page}{1} % page number for start of manuscript
\pagestyle[headings} % per your code
The rest of your document
\end{document}
```

Fiddle with this to get what you want.

Comment: To center text vertically use `\vspace*{\fill}`